# Plotting cylinders and planes on the same graph

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

How would I plot the cylinder $y^2 + z^2 = 9$ and the planes $x = 0$, $y = 3x$, and $z = 0$ in the same graph and in the first octant.

```
{
  y^2 + z^2 == 9,
  y == 3 x,
  z == 0
 }
```

Comment: Hi Brett, welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). What have you tried? Please show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of your code **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. Here it's considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts, please [edit] and improve your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[x, y, z];
ContourPlot3D[
 {
  y^2 + z^2 == 9,
  y == 3 x,
  z == 0
  }
 , {x, 0, 5}
 , {y, 0, 5}
 , {z, 0, 5}
 ]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot3D[
 {
  y^2 + z^2 == 9,
  y == 3 x,
  z == 0
  }
, {x, -12, 12}
, {y, -12, 12}
, {z, -12, 12}
]
```

[image]

[image]